# Passing Realm objects between ViewControllers

Tags: swift, realm

How would you go about passing Realm objects between controllers?

Would you pass just the ID and then fetch the object in the new controller or just pass the whole Realm object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current best practice is to just fetch again. If you are working off of a background thread, you can pass primary keys to the main thread and fetch with those. It's not that big of a performance issue in the thousand of objects due to how realm handles the loading of objects

Comment: I ended up going with this solution, after my research, I also think that is the best practice.

Comment: Awesome, we are working on the ability to pass objects but still thinking about how that would work exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the best approach is to pass primary keys, however I couldn't find a way to query for just the primary keys. Looks like you'd have to first query to get objects; map them to primary keys; then pass them to another thread.

Comment: This is correct, the best way to do this would be in a background thread. Since realm lazily loads down to the property it can be efficient when getting your primary keys