# passing Realm transaction between ViewModels

Tags: c#, uwp, realm, template10

Note: this is not the same as [Passing Realm objects between ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593921/passing-realm-objects-between-viewcontrollers)

I am trying to find a way to pass a Realm `Transaction` between two `ViewModel`s. Currently, the `Transaction` is opened in a detail view, so I can only access it in the detail view. I have a need to `Dispose` it back in the master view, so I am thinking that I could begin the `Transaction` before navigating to the detail view, like so:

```
var trans = realm.BeginWrite();
NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage), trans);
```

However, a Realm `Transaction` is not serializable, so this method does not work. I am using Template10 in a UWP application. In a Xamarin application (QuickJournal example), this can be accomplished like this:

```
var transaction = realm.BeginWrite();
...
var page = new JournalEntryDetailsPage(new JournalEntryDetailsViewModel(entry, transaction));
Navigation.PushAsync(page);
```

As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to pass arguments to a constructor using Template10's `NavigationService`. I would be happy to be able to either: a) pass the `Transaction` from the master view to the detail view in the constructor, or b) somehow access the detail view's `Transaction` from the master view.

My current workaround is to not use a `Transaction` at all, but to create an unmanaged copy of the `RealmObject` in the detail view, but this doesn't seem like a great permanent solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a poor man's injection cache to work around the serialization limitation:

```
public static class Injector
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, object> _dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, object>();

    public static Guid Store(object value)
    {
        var key = Guid.NewGuid();
        _dict.TryAdd(key, value);
        return key;
    }

    public static object Retrieve(Guid guid)
    {
        if (!_dict.TryRemove(guid, out var result))
        {
            throw new Exception("Key not found");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then in your master ViewModel you could do:

```
var key = Injector.Store(realm.BeginWrite());
NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage), key);
```

And then in your detail ViewModel, you can retrieve the transaction:

```
_transaction = Injector.Retrieve(key);
```

Comment: Much appreciated! I will give this a try this evening when I have my project handy. I was trying to come up with a way to pass the `Transaction` without passing the `Transaction` object itself, but wasn't finding any method to "find" an open `Transaction` in Realm. This looks like it should do the trick.